# different indention in yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

In differente examples i came across following kind of configuration ...

```
   ...   
      volumes:
        - name: my-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: my-web
        image: nginx
   ...
```

why the difference of the indention?
why is the vol node element(- name: my-pv) more indented than the containers node element (- name: my-web)? Has that anything to say? I could not find any explanation for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both blocks

```
volumes:
  - name: my-pv
```

and

```
containers:
- name: my-web
```

are structurally similar - they represents list of objects.
YAML allows that. For sake of consistency, use either of styles, but not both. This is exactly yamllint's [indentation rules](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rules.html#module-yamllint.rules.indentation) are for.